# Apache & Tomcat routing config: www.comapny -> apache; xxx.company -> tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I have an Apache & Tomcat installation, and need to configure it as follows.

- www.companyName.com/ -> Wordpress site, served through Apache
- www.companyName.com/** -> Wordpress site, served through Apache (Except as below)
- www.companyName.com/Register.html -> Registration application, handled through tomcat
- xxx.companyName.com/ -> Main application, handled through tomcat.

(Note, the final xxx.companyName is a catch-all, as the tomcat application will handle processing and routing based on the subdomain)

Note that Tomcat is currently running on port 8080.  I'd prefer the URL not to show the port number.  Should I reconfigure tomcat?  (I doubt I can have both tomcat and apache listening on port 80...)

How & where would I configure this routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [mod_proxy_ajp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) in apache. It is a tomcat connector, so it will proxy the requests for dynamic content to the tomcat server.